# Bulk Upsert in Couchbase with using Golang

Tags: go, couchbase, deadlock, bulkupdate, golang-migrate

I'm new to Golang
Please help with understanding

I want to use bulk upsert operation via gocb.collection_bulk.go.
How does it work if at the time of replacing the document, it will be blocked

Is this operation responsible for the moment of blocking or will an error fall? If an error falls, how do I process it to understand which document has fallen and try to replase it again

```
bulkContainer.AddUpsertOp(convertToDocumentId(oraData.IdentifierType, oraData.Identifier), &model.CouchbaseCustomer{Customer: oraData})

err := cl.scope.Collection(collectionName).Do(bulkContainer.ops, &gocb.BulkOpOptions{Context: ctx, Timeout: waitingTimeout})
```

Thanks for the explanation